# What is the correct way to use v8::Locker, and why must I use it?

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, v8

I'm trying to embed v8 in an Android application using NDK.

I have a JNI module that looks something like this (JNI mapping code not shown):

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>

#include <v8.h>
using namespace v8;

static jlong getMagicNumber() {
  HandleScope handle_scope;
  Persistent<Context> context = Context::New();
  Context::Scope context_scope(context);

  Handle<String> source = String::New("40 + 2");

  Handle<Script> script = Script::Compile(source);
  Handle<Value> result = script->Run();

  context.Dispose();

  return result->NumberValue();
}
```

The first time I run `getMagicNumber`, it correctly runs and returns 42. The second time I try to run it, it crashes.

Specifically, this `ASSERT` seen in v8's `isolate.h` fails:

```
// Returns the isolate inside which the current thread is running.
INLINE(static Isolate* Current()) {
  Isolate* isolate = reinterpret_cast<Isolate*>(
      Thread::GetExistingThreadLocal(isolate_key_));
  ASSERT(isolate != NULL);
  return isolate;
}
```

It sounds a lot like [this problem](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/v8-users/Px0JcsfDjYA), which suggests using `v8::Locker` to obtain "exclusive access to the isolate".

By adding a simple `Locker l;` to the top of `getMagicNumber`, the crash no longer occurs. Problems that fix themselves that easily tend to break themselves when I'm not paying attention.

I only have the most tenuous understanding of why this fixes my problem, and I'm getting compiler warnings that I'm using `v8::Locker` in a deprecated fashion. The recommended method is to provide it with a `v8::Isolate` as an argument to `v8::Locker`'s constructor, but I have no idea how I'm supposed to "obtain" an isolate.

Ultimately: What is the proper way to solve this problem according to the current state of v8, and *why*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I understand it, a V8 isolate is an instance of the V8 runtime, complete with a heap, a garbage collector, and zero or more V8 contexts. Isolates are *not* thread-safe and must be protected via `v8::Locker`.

In general, to use V8 you must first create an isolate:

```
v8::Isolate* isolate = v8::Isolate::New();
```

Then, to use the isolate from any thread:

```
v8::Locker locker(isolate);
v8::Isolate::Scope isolateScope(isolate);
```

At this point the thread owns the isolate and is free to create contexts, execute scripts, etc.

Now, for the benefit of very simple applications, V8 provides a default isolate and relaxes the locking requirement, but you can only use these crutches if you always access V8 from the same thread. My guess is that your application failed because the second call was made from a different thread.

Comment: I still don't fully understand what each of those lines do, but this worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am just learning V8 now, but I think you need to call:

v8::Locker locker(isolate);

This will create a stack allocated Locker object which will block the Isolate from being used on another thread.  When the current function returns this stack object's destructor will be called automatically causing the Isolate to be unlocked.

The you need to call:

v8::Isolate::Scope isolateScope(isolate);

This sets the current thread to run this Isolate.  Isolates can only be used on one thread.  The Locker enforces this, but the Isolate itself needs to be configured for the current thread.  This creates a stack allocated object which specifies which Isolate is associated with the current thread.  Just like the Locker, when this variable goes out of scope (when the current function returns) the Scope destructor gets called to un-set the Isolate as the default.  I believe this is needed because many of the V8 API calls need a reference to an Isolate, but don't take one as a parameter.  Therefore they need one they can access directly (probably through per-thread variables).

All the Isolate::Scope class does is call isolate::Enter() in the constructor and isolate::Exit() in the destructor.  Therefore if you want more control you can call Enter()/Exit() yourself.