# Read access violation while using v8::Debug::SetMessageHandler

Tags: c++, v8

I'm trying implement V8 debugger in my Qt application but I get exception.

I have 2 threads: main (that handle GUI and debugger commands) and engine thread (that run javascript code).

1. In main thread i'm initializing V8 by calling:

   ```
   V8::InitializeICU();
   mPlatform = platform::CreateDefaultPlatform();
   V8::InitializePlatform(mPlatform);
   V8::Initialize();
   ```
2. I'm creating an isolate in engine thread:

   ```
   ArrayBufferAllocator* allocator = new ArrayBufferAllocator();
   Isolate::CreateParams create_params;
   create_params.array_buffer_allocator = allocator;
   isolate = Isolate::New(create_params);
   ```
3. In main thread I'm using SetMessageHandler

   ```
   isolate->Enter();
   v8::Debug::SetMessageHandler(HandleMessage);

   // HandlMessage function: 
   void HandleMessage(const v8::Debug::Message& message) {
       v8::String::Utf8Value response(message.GetJSON());
       // TODO do something with |response|
   }
   ```
4. At line with SetMessageHandler I get read access violation

   Here is call stack:

   [image: Call stack]

FWIW I'd asked on [v8-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/v8-users/YT3IhM6oI2c) discussion group also. (no answers yet)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ben Noordhuis answered me [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/v8-users/YT3IhM6oI2c) I should use v8::Locker to synchronize isolates between threads. Here is [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15603393/1794387). Also, there was a missing of `isolate->Exit()` after `v8::Debug::SetMessageHandler(HandleMessage);`